# Java Socket Listener Issue?

Tags: java, php, sockets, bukkit

I have been stuck on this for a while now. I am trying to send data to the Java, server with PHP. When i load the plugin in Bukkit, it stops loading when i call this function:

```
public void SocketListen()
{       

    String clientSentence;
    String capitalizedSentence;

    try
    {

        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(25566);

        while(true)
        {
           Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
           BufferedReader inFromClient =
              new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
           DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
           clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
           System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
           capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
           outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        getLogger().severe(e.toString());
    }

}
```

which tells me i did something wrong. My PHP is:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; 
$port = 25566;
$data = 'test\n';

if ( ($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === FALSE )
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
else 
{
    echo "Attempting to connect to '$host' on port '$port'...<br>";
    if ( ($result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port)) === FALSE )
        echo "socket_connect() failed. Reason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
    else {
        echo "Sending data...<br>";
        socket_write($socket, $data, strlen($data));
        echo "OK<br>";

        echo "Reading response:<br>";
        while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
            echo $out;
        }
    }
    socket_close($socket);      
}
?>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Basically, i just need the PHP server to send "Hello" then the Java Client Spit it out with getLogger().info(data);

Also, do i need to Port forward 25566 on the Client or the server with PHP? They are both hosted on my Local Network with the same External IP.

Comment: Does minecraft not use port: 25565? @user2310289

Comment: you're writing everything on one line?

Comment: sorry need to put my glasses on.

Comment: What do you mean? Also, do i port forward the port on the Side with the PHP, or the side with the Java Client?

Comment: Try popping a '\n' somewhere in the client.

Comment: @Dru which one do i need to port forward?

Comment: like here, echo "Sending data...<br>\n";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be due to the fact that the loop never stops:

```
 while(true)
    {
      //code
```

you can use the class i made for java server and clients:

## ChatCleint

```
    package com.weebly.foxgenesis.src;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public final class ChatClient
{  
    private Socket socket = null;
    private DataOutputStream streamOut = null;
    private ChatClientThread client = null;
    private String serverName = "localhost";
    private int serverPort = -1;
    private final ChatReciever output;

/**
 * Create a new ChatClient that connects to a given server and receives UTF-8 encoded messages
 * @param a Client class
 */
public ChatClient(ChatReciever chatReciever)
{ 
    output = chatReciever;
    serverPort = chatReciever.getPort();
    serverName = chatReciever.getHost();
    connect(serverName, serverPort);
}

private void connect(String serverName, int serverPort)
{  
    output.handleLog("Establishing connection. Please wait ...");
    try
    {  
        socket = new Socket(serverName, serverPort);
        output.handle("Connected to chat server");
        open();
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException uhe)
    {  
        output.handleError("Host unknown: " + uhe.getMessage()); 
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {  
        output.handleError("Unexpected exception: " + ioe.getMessage()); 
    } 
}

/**
 * Sends a message to the server through bytes in UTF-8 encoding 
 * @param msg message to send to the server
 */
public void send(String msg) throws IOException
{  
    streamOut.writeUTF(msg); 
    streamOut.flush();
}

/**
 * forces the ChatReciever to listen to a message (NOTE: this does not send anything to the server)
 * @param msg message to send
 */
public void handle(String msg)
{  
    output.handle(msg);
}

private void open() throws IOException
{   
    streamOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    client = new ChatClientThread(this, socket); 
}

/**
 * tries to close 
 */
public void close() throws IOException
{  
    if (streamOut != null)  
        streamOut.close();
    if (socket    != null)  
        socket.close(); 
}

/**
 * closes the client connection
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void stop()
{
    if(client != null)
        client.stop();
    client = null;
}

/**
 * checks if the ChatClient is currently connected to the server
 * @return Boolean is connected
 */
public boolean isConnected()
{
    return client == null ?(false) : (true);
}
}
```

## ChatServerThread

```
   package com.weebly.foxgenesis.src;



import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public final class ChatClientThread extends Thread
{  
    private Socket           socket   = null;
    private ChatClient       client   = null;
    private DataInputStream  streamIn = null;

    public ChatClientThread(ChatClient _client, Socket _socket)
    {  
        client   = _client;
        socket   = _socket;
        open();  
        start();
    }
    public void open()
    {  
        try
        {  
            streamIn  = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {  
            System.out.println("Error getting input stream: " + ioe);
            client.stop();
        }
    }
    public void close()
    {  
        try
        {  
            if (streamIn != null) streamIn.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {  
            System.out.println("Error closing input stream: " + ioe);
        }
    }
    public void run()
    {  
        while (true)
        {  
            try
            {  
                client.handle(streamIn.readUTF());
            }
            catch(IOException ioe)
            { 
                System.out.println("Listening error: " + ioe.getMessage());
                client.stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## ChatReciever

```
 package com.weebly.foxgenesis.src;

public interface ChatReciever 
{
    /**
     * gets the IP address of the host
     * @return String IP address
     */
    public String getHost();

    /**
     * gets the port of the host
     * @return Integer port of host
     */
    public int getPort();

    /**
     * sends a message from the server to the implementing class
     * @param msg message from the server
     */
    public void handle(String msg);

    /**
     * sends an error to the implementing class
     * @param errorMsg error message
     */
    public void handleError(String errorMsg);

    /**
     * Sends a message to the log
     * @param msg message to send
     */
    public void handleLog(Object msg);
}
```